# Best way to drive N or P MOSFETs from ESP8266

Tags: mosfet, esp8266, mosfet-driver

I have a project that requires me to control several 12 V peripherals (motors/LEDs/solenoids) up to 5 A.

My controller will be either an ESP32/ESP8266, I will have regulated 5 V and also an unregulated 12 V-15 V supply  with common ground available to provide MOSFET switching.

I would ideally like a component that can be relatively easily hand soldered.

I am looking for the simplest (least components) way to control up to 8 devices including PWM.

My thinking is ESP32 - MOSFET driver - 5 V MOSFET (IRF520) - Load

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Search for "load switch" or "load driver" from international distributors such as Digikey, Mouser, RS, Farnell, ... If you are good at SMD component soldering then you can find lots. A crude search has shown me 500+ ICs and almost half of them large enough to solder by hand easily.

Comment: Simplest? Hand soldering? Relay modules are very convenient, and also bulky. IMO MOSFET driver is often not needed (but find out) but if you have one you may as well use the unregulated supply to control the gate and not rely on a low voltage MOSFET.

Comment: Many MOSFETs are relatively big parts in through-hole packages with long leads, so hand soldering is no problem.

Comment: The IRF520 is in no way a 5 V mosfet. It has a maximum threshold voltage of 4 V, and to drive a MOSFET fully on you typically want to drive it with a voltage about 2 or 3 times its threshold voltage. The IRF520's only Rdson rating is at 10 V gate to source, so I wouldn't generally use it with a gate voltage much less than that. Look for "logic level" FETs if you want to drive it at 5 V. Those will have threshold voltages of 1-2 volts, and high enough transconductance to get a good on resistance at 5 V.

Comment: i would suggest a logic level fet, like the irlz44n, which cuts on pretty hard even at 3.3v, but if you have a driver or even  level shifter to feed it 12v, that's going to work better even on non-logic-level fets. This is especially important when dealing with PWM as lower voltages not only yeild higher rds, they are slower to switch on/off as well, which makes for even more heat/waste.